# JQuery Validation including rules dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am looking for a way to include the jquery validation rules dynamically, because I need to use them in different places.

The user can edit for example a news in two ways. The first way is a usual form with jquery validation. This is no problem, its all working fine. 
But I also want to use the jquery validation with jeditable without repeating my rules.

So at the moment I have a NewsValidator.js like this:

```
$("form").validate({

rules: {
        title: {
                required: true,
        rangelength:[3,50],
                },
        content: {
                required: true,
                rangelength: [25, 250]
                }
        },
});
```

And my code for the jeditable field looks like this:

```
$('.edit').editable('http://localhost/news/ajax', { 
        'id': 'news_id',
        'name':'title',
        'method': 'put',
        submitdata : {
                        _method: "PUT",
                        content: $("div.content").text(),

                    },

 error: function(){
    alert('Something went wrong');
 },
 onsubmit: function(settings, td) {
    $.getScript('../../js/validation/NewsValidator.js'); //-> this is not working (unexspected ) )

}
```

});

So does anyone know how I can use my validator inside the onsubmit function without copy&paste to keep it DRY?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Load the script unconditionally to get the validation configured, and use `if ($("form").valid())` in the `onsubmit` handler.

Comment: What do you mean with unconditionally? Can you please explain it or give an example?

Comment: You're currently loading the script using `$.getScript` only after the user submits something. I suggest you just add `<script src="../../js/validation/newsValidator.js">` to the page, so it loads always.

Comment: Maybe it was too late yesterday or too obvious. Anyway, this doesn't work for me. The newsvalidator is never called. And if I try to change the function of news validator to $(this).validate() I get an exception: Cannot read properties of undefined.

Comment: `$(this).validate()` does not even make any sense in the context of the code you've shown us.   And you cannot call `.validate()` multiple times on the same form.  It's called _once_ on DOM ready to initialize the plugin on your form, and any subsequent calls are ignored.  In other words, you cannot repeat `.validate()` even if you wanted.  That's why the developer provides methods such as `.rules('add')` in order to dynamically manipulate the setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"I am looking for a way to include the jquery validation rules dynamically"*

The only way to add, change, or remove the rules dynamically is by using [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/).

`.rules('add')` to dynamically add new rule(s) or over-write existing rule(s).

`.rules('remove')` to dynamically remove existing rule(s).

**Examples**:

```
$('#myField').rules('add', {  // <- a single field
    required: true, 
    digits: true
});

$('.manyFields').each(function() {  // <- multiple fields at once needs '.each()'
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true, 
        digits: true
    });
});

$('#myField').rules('add', {  // <- a single field with custom messages
    required: true, 
    digits: true,
    messages: {
        required: "this field is mandatory",
        digits: "this field can only contain digits"
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT**:

The `.validate()` method is what's used to *initialize* the plugin on your form.  It's called *once* on DOM ready to initialize the plugin on your form, and any subsequent calls are ignored.  In other words, you cannot repeat `.validate()` even if you wanted.  That's why the developer provides methods such as `.rules('add')` in order to dynamically manipulate the setup.

Since it's actually impossible to repeat the `.validate()` method, where you're repeating any code is entirely unclear.

Comment: I know this, but than I have to repeat myself. I only want to declare the rules for the news once and use them in both cases (normal form and jeditable page)

Comment: @MarcoMartens, what you're trying to do is not clear.  Yes, we know you don't want to repeat any code.  However, you cannot just load an external JavaScript file dynamically like that... JavaScript is typically loaded when the page loads.  Otherwise, to dynamically manipulate the page, you must use the methods provided by the plugin developer such as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: @MarcoMartens, also see my edit.  You've not shown or explained enough, but for what little you've shown, it is not possible.

Comment: I am a beginner at js, so I thought there is a way to include the rules or something. I didn't know that the validate function can only initialized once, so that was the point.

I will try to implement it as you said in your answer.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sparky, how to change default error  message to add rules?

Comment: @whoami, I edited the answer with an example.  Please refer to the documentation for `.rules()` which is linked within the answer that shows a clear example.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you